# Change Logo in Firebase Authentication Pop-Up

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to figure out how to change the logo on the sign-up / sign-in pop-up that users are presented with on my app, which is setup via Firebase Authentication. I've dug around all the settings in my Firebase Console, but haven't seen any option to change the logo. I can't find anything about changing the app logo in the Firebase documentation either. Any guidance would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Please provide more details, are you developing an android, iOS, cross-platform or web app? Also provide the snippet of code where you open the sign in pop up.

Comment: This is a web app. I'm not a dev myself so aren't sure what code is used to open the sign in pop up...but I can try and find this out if this is necessary in order to change the logo?